# How to fix Device: (3:2294) null is not an object (evaluating 'f.getRandomBase64') uuid react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, uuid

I am learning react-native using snack expo and am trying to generate random unique numbers for my components but I get an error when I test my app on an android and iOS but it's works okay with the web:

```
Device: (3:2294) null is not an object (evaluating 'f.getRandomBase64')
```

This is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
     {uuidv4()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is my [snack link](https://snack.expo.io/@afasha/ef36cf)

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: I was informed that it's an issue with expo maybe try upvoting this question and check https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/429

Answer (score 2):

Rebuilding the app after installing `react-native-get-random-values` solved it for me.

After installing `react-native-get-random-values`:

1. `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
2. Removed the app from simulator/device and reinstalled it.

PS. This issue didn't appear while the debugger was working.